# How to show recording time in flutter?

Tags: flutter, camera, flutter-dependencies, video-capture

How can I show the time of a recording video in flutter. I am using the [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera)(^0.9.4+16) package.

```
        Future<String?> _startVideoRecording() async {
          
            if (!controller!.value.isInitialized) {
              Fluttertoast.showToast(
                  msg: 'Please wait',
                  toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                  gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                  timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                  textColor: Colors.white);
        
              return null;
            }
            // Do nothing if a recording is on progress
            if (controller!.value.isRecordingVideo) {
        
              return null;
            }
        
            final Directory appDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
            final String videoDirectory = '${appDirectory.path}/Videos';
            await Directory(videoDirectory).create(recursive: true);
            final String currentTime = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
            final String filePath = '$videoDirectory/${currentTime}.mp4';
        
            try {
              await controller!.startVideoRecording();
              videoPath = filePath;
            } on CameraException catch (e) {
              _showCameraException(e);
              return null;
            }
        
            return file Path;
          }
```

Here is an example [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/runeE.png).

Answer (score 1):

```
  String recordingTime = '0:0'; // to store value
  bool isRecording = false;

  void recordTime() {
    var startTime = DateTime.now();
    Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) {
      var diff = DateTime.now().difference(startTime);

      recordingTime =
          '${diff.inHours < 60 ? diff.inHours : 0}:${diff.inMinutes < 60 ? diff.inMinutes : 0}:${diff.inSeconds < 60 ? diff.inSeconds : 0}';

      print(recordingTime);

      if (!isRecording) {
        t.cancel(); //cancel function calling
      }

      setState(() {});
    });
  }
```

now use  recordingTime

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Mohit for Your answer

Please use the updated function.

```
String recordingTime = '0:0'; // to store value
 bool isRecording = false;

 void recordTime() {
    var startTime = DateTime.now();
    Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 0), (Timer t) {
      var diff = DateTime.now().difference(startTime);
      recordingTime =
          '${diff.inHours == 0 ? '' : diff.inHours.toString().padLeft(2, 
"0") + ':'}${(diff.inMinutes % 60).floor().toString().padLeft(2, 
"0")}:${(diff.inSeconds % 60).floor().toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
      if (!isRecording) {
        t.cancel();
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be to use the [Stopwatch class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Stopwatch-class.html)
along with the [Timer.periodic constructor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer/Timer.periodic.html):

Something like this:

```dart
final stopwatch = Stopwatch();
```

```dart
void startRecording() {
  // start your recorder

  stopwatch.start();
  Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
    if (!stopwatch.isRunning) {
      timer.cancel();
    }
    setState(() {}); // to update the timer on-screen
  });
}
```

```dart
  CustomTimer(duration: stopwatch.elapsed) // make your own widget (here CustomTimer) to display your timer if you want
```

```dart
class CustomTimer extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomTimer({required this.duration});

  final Duration duration;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final recordingTime = duration.toString().split('.').first.padLeft(8, '0');

    return Text(recordingTime);
  }
}
```

Note: you just need to make sure that your `stopwatch` starts if your recording has successfully started